# "Gave up teaching me" or "gave up on teaching me"?

Tags: grammar

Should I  write:

> He was my tutor when everyone gave up teaching me.

or

> My tutor when everyone gave up on teaching me.

Answer (score 1):

You would write:

> He was my tutor when everyone (else) **gave up on** teaching me.

*gave up on* here is used as a phrasal verb. See [give up on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/give-up-on)

else is a good word to add, since your tutor was the one that did not give up on you. It sounds more natural this way.

Comment: I think *had given* would be more correct here, no? Because they have already given up by the time he becomes the tutor.

Comment: That could be the usual British/American difference, @starsplusplus.  To my American ear, the present perfect sounds too formal for the phrasal verb.

Comment: "He was my tutor _when_ everyone else gave up on teaching me." sounds fine to my AmE ear, and I think "He was my tutor _after_ everyone else had given up on teaching me." would be the way I would phrase it with "had given".

Comment: Yet the link you provide says the direct object of *give up on* is **someone.** So, shouldn't it either be *gave up teaching me* or *gave up on me (as a student, for example)*?

Answer (score 1):

The phases "give up" and "give up on" have different meanings. You give up doing something means you stop doing something, whereas you give up on somebody, which means to believe that somebody is never going to get better, arrive or to be found.

So the correct sentence is "He was my tutor when everyone gave up teaching me".